# How can I insert data in Firebase with a custom key using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to insert data without having a key automatically generated:

```
 var database = firebase.database();
 const dbRef = firebase.database().ref();

 const usersRef = dbRef.child('links/business000000/');

 // this object will hold the new user information
 let newUser = {};

 // loop through View to get the data for the model 
 for (let i = 0, len = 63; i < len; i++) {

     var newPostRef = usersRef.setValue("business000000"+toString(i));

     newPostRef.set({
         image: "business000000"+toString(i)+"jpg",
         next_link: "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language",
         prev_link: "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language",
         za_link: "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
    });
}
```

What should I do? I get the "setvalue is not a function" error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of what you're doing now, just build a new reference to each new child node under /links by calling `child()` with the name for that node.

```
const linksRef = dbRef.child('links');

for (let i = 0, len = 63; i < len; i++) {
    const name = "business000000" + i;
    var newPostRef = linksRef.child(name);
    newPostRef.set({
        image: name + "jpg",
        next_link: "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language",
        prev_link: "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language",
        za_link: "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, can call `child` with a path such as: `dbRef.child("links/" + name)` or `dbRef.child("links/business/" + name)`.

```js
   let name;
   for (let i = 0, len = 63; i < len; i++) {
        name = `business000000${i}`;
        dbRef.child(`links/${name}`).set({
             image: `${name}.jpg`,
             next_link: "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language",
             prev_link: "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language",
             za_link: "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
        });
    }
```